# how to compare two data frame on one string column that the number of samples are different pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have two data frame and there are two columns that I want to check them. The number of samples in two data frame are different. I tried to do that in two ways but raises error that `ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects`.

```
dftrain

text
Hello
How are you?
I'm doing fine..
Agent please ...
Hiiiiii
```

```
dftest

text
hello
How are you?
Im doing fine
Agent please
```

So the result would be:

```
text
How are you?
```

I did this:
`comparison_column = np.where(dftest["text"] == dftrain["text"], True, False)`
but it seems its for the cases where the number of samples in both data frame are the same.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49691342/pandas-compare-data-frame-columns-with-different-shapes) link close to what I need but still is different.

Comment: It's likely [the index are different](https://cumsum.wordpress.com/2020/08/26/valueerror-can-only-compare-identically-labeled-series-objects/) try `reset_index`.

Comment: @Psidom thanks for your comment. But numpy does not have `reset_index`. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: No `dftest["text"]` is a pandas Series not numpy array. And the error comes from this line `dftest["text"] == dftrain["text"]`

Comment: Yea I just tried that and got the same error `np.where(dftest["text"].reset_index() == dftrain["text"].reset_index(), True, False)`

Comment: Have you checked the workaround in the above post ? TLDR: add `drop=True` in `reset_index`

Comment: Looks more like you want the intersection (`set(dftrain['text']).intersection(dftest['text'])`), which can either be done with sets or an inner merge, or a simple list comprehension `[x for x in dftest['text'] if x in dftrain['text']]`

Comment: @Psidom Yes but the workaround is for data frames with equal number of samples. AmI missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply on the smallest DataFrame like `dftest` then check in `unique()` values in largest DataFrame like `dftrain` like below :

```
>>> dftrain = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['text', 'Hello', 'How are you?', 'Hello', 'Hello' , 'Hello']})

>>> dftest = pd.DataFrame({'col2': ['text', 'hello', 'How are you?', 'hello']})

>>> dftest.loc[dftest['col2'].apply(lambda x : x in dftrain.col1.unique()), 'col2']

0            text
2    How are you?
Name: col2, dtype: object

>>> dftest.loc[dftest['col2'].apply(lambda x : x in dftrain.col1.unique()), 'col2'].tolist()

['text', 'How are you?']
```

Comment: Thanks, Does it consider the lower case, ? ! ... also?

Comment: @sariii yes this is possible but in your question you didn't consider loswer case

Comment: @sariii if you give example i can handle this

Comment: Sorry I meant if the words are different in case it does not consider that right?

Comment: @sariii yes you can see for `Hello` and `hello` this is correct